# Why is $this is empty when using load() in laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So I have these 2 tables

```
components
=========================
| id | code | type      |
=========================
|  1 | E1   | Engine    |
|  2 | G1   | Generator |
|  3 | E2   | Engine    |
=========================

formulas /* engine_id and generator_id reference to component id */
=============================================
| id | engine_id | generator_id | diesel_id |
=============================================
|  1 |         1 |            2 |         1 |
|  2 |         3 |            2 |         1 |
=============================================
```

So in Model/Component.php, I created this eloquent function

```
public function formulas()
{
    $foreignKey = $this->type === 'Engine' ? 'engine_id' : 'generator_id';

    return $this->hasMany(Formula::class, $foreignKey);
}
```

It is working fine if I use `$component->formulas`. But I have to call diesel for each formula too. I don't like to use load() inside a loop.

```
// ComponentController.php
public function show(Component $component)
{
    $component->formulas->each(function ($formula) {
        //if this component has 100 formulas, then it will do 100 query to table diesels
        $formula->load('diesel');
    });

    return $component;
}
```

So I want to use `$component->load('formulas.diesel')`, but `$this` is always empty and the foreign key will always set as `'generator_id'`

```
// Component.php
public function formulas()
{
    $foreignKey = $this->type === 'Engine' ? 'engine_id' : 'generator_id';
    info($this); // this will be called twice, but only first call has value.

    return $this->hasMany(Formula::class, $foreignKey);
}

// ComponentController.php
public function show(Component $component)
{
    info('=== 1 ===');
    $component->formulas;
    info('=== 2 ===');

    return $component->load('formulas');
}

// Outputs in Laravel.log
[2020-02-28 18:15:08] testing.INFO: === 1 ===  
[2020-02-28 18:15:08] testing.INFO: {"id":1,"code":"E1","type":"Engine"}  
[2020-02-28 18:15:08] testing.INFO: === 2 ===  
[2020-02-28 18:15:08] testing.INFO: []  <------ why is this empty??
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ->with() or ->load() functions called [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).
It Is intended to solve N+1 problem.

It means Laravel won't generate query for every Component model like:

```
select * from formulas where engine_id = 1
select * from formulas where generator_id = 2
...
```

It will call one query for all the models using their ids like:

```
select * from formulas where generator_id in (1, 2, 3, ...)
```

In this regard you cannot use "this", because formulas() function will be called from "empty instance" of your Component model just to identify the relation.

To understand better you can read the documentation about [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: Any idea what should I do if I need conditional $this when doing eager loading?